# Recover damaged lotus

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a problem.I am getting an error message: Database is damaged, cannot allocate space. when accessing one of  Lotus Notes databases.  I have tried fixup, compact and updall to no avail.  Any suggestions? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well…try this steps:

1. Open the "Start" menu and click "Computer" or "My Computer" depending on your version of Windows. Navigate to the C drive.
2. Open the "Notes" folder. Double-click on the "Notes.ini" file to open it in Notepad.
3. Place a semicolon (;) in front of the following two lines to temporarily disable VirusScan:
   AddInsMenus=NCMenu
   EXTMGR_ADDINS=NCExtMgr
4. Click the "Save" option from the "File" menu. Close Notes.ini.

Or visit: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/appvirtualization/en-US/612aacd1-c4ba-47eb-bf9c-0940d2ea1a05/lotus-notes-backup-data-nsf-file-corrupted?forum=itproxpsp
U can find info for solution this problem